# Blank / white screen for admin/utils/

Tags: admin

`/admin/utils/serverinfo` and `/admin/utils/phpinfo` are both showing empty pages. There aren't any errors appearing in any logs.

In case it's related, the same site won't allow .jpg images to be uploaded. The progress bar reaches 100% but then it remains stuck.

Running Craft Pro 2.5.2755.

**UPDATE**

Running devMode true revealed the following error:
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /nfs/c10/h03/mnt/175833/domains/example.com/craft/app/controllers/UtilsController.php on line 292`

Comment: Do you get any error message when you enable devMode?

Comment: @BradBell Added error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is a bug in Craft that's been fixed for the next release.  That line is PHP 5.4 array syntax and your server is still using PHP 5.3 (Craft still supports back to PHP 5.3).

In the meantime, you can go to the line it's complaining about and change:

```
$serverArray = [];
```

to:

```
$serverArray = array();
```

Comment: Awesome. That fixed those pages, but now this happens: http://ssdd.d.pr/ssbL

Comment: Hrm... clear your `craft/storage/runtime/logs` folder and try again.  Something might be jacked in there.